# Selecting a Datevalue from GridView Cell and Use it as Parameter to a SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, datagridview

Hi I am Presently running an ASP.NET application 
Now problem is with the Next button in the app, whenever someone clicks it, it returns the data of date range SYSDATE + 18 to SYDATE + 36 . But the way it should work is .. it should take the first date value from the GridView Date Cell and Returns the data for GridViewFirstCellDate+18 to GridViewFirstCellDate+36. My Gridview code is al follows. Eg the date in Image is Tuesday,November 19,2013 , so clicking Next button should retrun from 7/12/2013 and 25/12/2013 's data (DD/MM/YYYY)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="3" EnableModelValidation="True" GridLines="Horizontal" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Date">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Date" Runat="Server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("DUTY_DATE", "{0:dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy}") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Role">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Role" Runat="Server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("DUTY_DESC") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Officer's Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("FULLNAME") %>'  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ROW_PASS", "/sites/HQDO/Pages/OfficerDetails.aspx?_ID={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Officer's HomeNo">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="HomeNo" Runat="Server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("MOBILE_NO") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Officer's HomeNo">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="HomeNo" Runat="Server" 
                 Text='<%# Eval("OFFICE_TEL") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

and the CodeBehind for next button is below

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                            DataTable table = new DataTable();


            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT CONTACTS.ROWID as ROW_PASS,DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_DATE AS DUTY_DATE,DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE AS DUTY_TYPE,DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_OFFICER AS DUTY_OFFICER,DUTY_TYPES.DESCRIPTION AS DUTY_DESC,CONTACTS.SNAME AS FULLNAME,CONTACTS.MOBILE AS MOBILE_NO,CONTACTS.OFFICETEL AS OFFICE_TEL FROM DUTY_ROTA,DUTY_TYPES,CONTACTS WHERE DUTY_DATE between SYSDATE+18 and SYSDATE+36 AND DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE = DUTY_TYPES.DUTY_TYPE AND SNAME IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DUTY_DATE";


            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                    {

                        using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {

                            ODA.Fill(table);

                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
                }

            }

            //DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
            //DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";

            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

I tried to catch the value in below way

```
LabelDate.Text = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

And then convert it to Date and use it in my SQL. But the LabelDate.Text is unable to store the data not sure why.

Can you buddies please help How could I Capture GridView First Row First Cells data and Add 18 days to it...also I want to use it in my SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a handler for [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Here's a quick example:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    LabelDate.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but not working. Rather the Label becoming invisible not sure why. Is it a page_load issue I am facing?

Comment: Does the gridview get populated as you'd expect?

Comment: Yes GridView populates fine..But I am not really able to capture the First Columns First Row value...

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
LabelDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text).AddDays(18).ToShortDateString();
```

Or:

```
LabelDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text).AddDays(18).ToShortDateString();
```

Or:

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
 Label1.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text, "g", provider).AddDays(18).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working I am getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error.